# Yield having different behavior when iterated

Tags: python, generator

I have the following function::

```
def f123():
  lista = range(2)
  print("2: before yields")

  yield [lista, "A: yield"]
  print("- after yield A")

  yield [lista, "B: yield"]
  print("- after yield B")

  yield [lista, "C: yield"]
  print("- after yield C")
```

From what I've researched, I can take advantage of my `generator` by iterating over it or using the `next()` function to move the cursor.
So, I tried to implement two different ways in order to get the same answer, but without success!

**Example 1**:

```
print("0: -----")
print("1: start")

list_gener = f123()

example = list()
example.append(next(list_gener))
example.append(next(list_gener))
example.append(next(list_gener))

print("3: end")
print(example)
```

**Example 2**:

```
print("0: -----")
print("1: start")

example = [item for item in f123()]

print("3: end")
print(example)
```

**Contents** of the `example` variable:

```
[
   [range(0, 2), 'A: yield'], 
   [range(0, 2), 'B: yield'], 
   [range(0, 2), 'C: yield']
]
```

**Respective Answers**:

| Answer example 1 | Answer example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0: ----- | 0: ----- |
| 1: start | 1: start |
| 2: before yields | 2: before yields |
| after yield A | after yield A |
| after yield B | after yield B |
| 3: end | after yield C |
|  | 3: end |

**MY DOUBT IS:**
What causes `after yield C` to be printed during `loop` iteration?

I know that in the `next` example (example 1) it will never be printed because there is no more `yield` after that C, but how do I make example 1 behave the same as example 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get `After yield C` in example 1 because you never call `next(list_gener)` after getting `C: yield`. The generator is still suspended after the third `yield` call, waiting for you to call `next()` again to continue.

In example 2, iterating over the generator keeps calling `next()` until it gets a `StopIteration` exception. That happens when it calls again after getting `C: yield`, so the generator function continues to that `print()` statement.

You can get equivalent results if you call `next()` in a loop until the exception.

```
try:
    while True:
        example.append(next(list_gener))
except StopIteration:
    print("StopIteration")
```

Answer (score 1):

a generator doesn't return, it instead throws a `StopIteration` Exception once it reaches the end of its code to signal that it is done.

in your example2 when you use `for` it is going to call `next` repeatedly until it catches a `StopIteration` Exception.

in your example1 you only call `next` 3 times, so it reaches the third yield, but it never ran the code after it because `next` wasn't called again.

calling `next` another time in example 1 will cause the function to run to the end (therefore printing "- after yield C") then it is going to raise a `StopIteration` Exception which you should catch.

```py
print("0: -----")
print("1: start")

list_gener = f123()

example = list()
example.append(next(list_gener))
example.append(next(list_gener))
example.append(next(list_gener))
try:
    example.append(next(list_gener))
except StopIteration:
    print("caught the exception")

print("3: end")
print(example)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second example the comprehension loops until it catches a `StopIteration` exception from the generator, which happens automatically when the generator returns. When you manually step through the generator using `next` you aren't calling it a final time to get that `StopIteration` exception that indicates the generator is "empty".

Change your first test to something like this instead:

```py
# ...
example = list()
try:
    while True:
        example.append(next(list_gener))
except StopIteration:
    pass
# ...
```